# Oracle Apex Email Validation to accept single user mail id

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an item to enter the email id "item_email"

I need to give validation for email id item "item_email" that it should not accept more than one email ids.

Is there is any possible to do this, please help me to proceed on this.

Comment: Don't put tags "apex", "apex-code" and "plsqldeveloper" in questions about Oracle Apex. It is completely different technologies.

Answer (score 0):

A simple validation; count number of @s. For example:

```
SQL> with test as
  2  (select 'lf@gmail.com' email from dual union
  3   select 'lf@gmail.com bf@gmail.com' from dual
  4  )
  5  select regexp_count(email, '@') cnt
  6  from test;

       CNT
----------
         1
         2

SQL>
```

If such a query returns 1, item contains one "e-mail" address.

However, consider yet another validation - whether value entered into that item really looks like an e-mail. Because, if someone enters only "@", that would pass the previous validation, but it certainly isn't a valid e-mail address.

On the other hand, maybe you already perform that validation. In that case, disregard that objection.

[EDITED by LF, after reading OP's comment]:

Create a validation on the e-mail item (whose name is, for example, :P3_E_MAIL). Its type should be "PL/SQL function (returning error text)", and its code

```
if regexp_count(:P3_E_MAIL, '@') > 1 or
   not regexp_like(:P3_E_MAIL, '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$') 
then
   return ('E-mail address is incorrect');
end if;
```

See whether you're satisfied with such a code.

Comment: Hello Its not working if i add this query in email validation

Comment: you will need to adopt it before it will work. Perhaps supply what you've done so far

Comment: The below Validation used in apex for email text field, i am not able to add the email"jean-pierre.daltin@oracle.com" because of "-", i need to include this mail id also.please modify the below regular expression.

^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*,\s*|\s*$))*$

Comment: Bah! Wrongly interpreted the comment & reverted modification back.